# Quantum Harmonic Oscillator - $x^4$ expectation value

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I need to evaluate $\langle n| \hat{x}^4 |n\rangle$ for the quantum harmonic oscillator.
By replacing $\hat{x} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a})$ I've reduced the problem to the evaluation of $\langle n|(\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a})^4|n\rangle$, and I'm stuck here.
Any help? :)

Comment: Hint: you only need to consider combinations that have equal numbers of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^\dagger$

Comment: And with the use of the comment above, use the commutation relationship to arrange the terms in a such way, that the final result will have the form $\langle n | \alpha (\hat{a}^{\dagger})^2 a^2  + \beta |n \rangle$

Answer (score 1):

Since any  combination of the raising and the lowering operators with different powers will change the eigenstate to something other than $|n\rangle$, the inner-product with $\langle n|$ will vanish, along with that term. Therefore, you only need to consider those term(s) in the expansion of $(a+a^\dagger)^4$ where the two operators have the same power, then apply the formulas:
$$ a\, |n\rangle = \sqrt{n} \,\,|n-1\rangle$$ and
$$a^\dagger \, |n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1}\, \, |n+1\rangle$$ repeatedly for each of those term(s).